# When the main thread exits, do other threads also exit?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have a problem about main threads and other threads in the same process. When the main function returns, do the other threads exit too? I am confused about this.

Consider the following test code:

```
void* test1(void *arg)
{
    unsigned int i = 0;
    while (1){
        i+=1;
    }
    return NULL;
}

void* test2(void *arg)
{
    long double i = 1.0;
    while (1){
        i *= 1.1;
    }
    return NULL;
}

void startThread ( void * (*run)(void*), void *arg) {
  pthread_t t;
  pthread_attr_t attr;
  if (pthread_attr_init(&attr) != 0
      || pthread_create(&t, &attr, run, arg) != 0
      || pthread_attr_destroy(&attr) != 0
      || pthread_detach(t) != 0) {
    printf("Unable to launch a thread\n");
    exit(1);
  }
}

int main()
{
    startThread(test1, NULL);
    startThread(test2, NULL);

    sleep(4);
    printf("main thread return.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

When the "main thread return." prints out, thread test1 and test2 also exit， can anyone tell me why?

Comment: The text of the question doesn't match the question body. Is this about what happens when the main thread exits? Or is this about what happens when the main thread returns from the `main` function? (Obviously, the thread can't return if it exits. It can do one or the other.)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

When the main thread returns (i.e., you return from the `main` function), it terminates the entire process.  This includes all other threads.  The same thing happens when you call `exit`. You can avoid this by calling `pthread_exit`.

The purpose of `pthread_detach` is to make it so you don't need to join with other threads in order to release their resources.  Detaching a thread does not make it exist past process termination, it will still be destroyed along with all the other threads.

Comment: This answer as written is not true. When the main thread (or any thread) calls `exit`, or when the initial invocation of `main` returns, the entire process exits. But the main thread can exit with `pthread_exit` without affecting other threads.

Comment: @R.. Does it mean that it is possible for a process to exit, but its threads continue execution?

Comment: @hsalimi: It is not possible for threads to continue after the process has exited. R is saying that is possible for the main thread to exit through `pthread_exit` with other threads continuing.

Comment: @hsalimi: No. Threads are part of the process. If the process exits, they (along with all other process resources) cease to exist. Termination of the initial thread via `pthread_exit` does not cause the process to exit.

Answer (score 30):

You should use [`pthread_join()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_join.html) on each of the new threads, to inform the calling thread to wait on the sub-threads, suspending execution - and process exit - until those threads terminate.

Calling [`pthread_detach`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/pthread_detach.html) on the created threads **won't** keep them around after a process exits. From the linux [man page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_detach.3.html):

> The detached attribute merely determines the behavior of the system when the thread terminates; it does not prevent the thread from being terminated if the process terminates using exit(3) (or equivalently, if the main thread returns).

You'll sometimes see a [`pthread_exit`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_exit.html) in `main` used instead of explicit `pthread_join` calls, the intent being that exiting `main` in this way will allow other threads to continue running. In fact, the [linux man page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_exit.3.html) states this explicitly:

> To allow other threads to continue execution, the main thread should terminate by calling pthread_exit() rather than exit(3).

But I don't know if this is expected behavior on all platforms, and I've always stuck to using `pthread_join`.

`pthread_join` requires the `pthread_t` for the target thread, so your code will need to change a bit since you need to create both threads before calling `pthread_join` to wait for them both. So you can't call it in `startThread`. You'll need to return a `pthread_t`, or pass a pointer to a `pthread_t` to your `startThread` function.

Comment: Read the docs for [`pthread_detach`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_detach.html) carefully. It doesn't do what you seem to think.

Comment: @laifjei Maybe you are mistaking detach with the functionality provided e. g. in Java/C#/Python/etc. - daemon threads. Java internally keeps the process alive while any non-daemon threads are left alive (even though the main thread dies).

Answer (score 1):

All the threads in your process will be terminated when you return from `main()`.

The `libc` library is the one responsible for implementing this behavior by calling `exit()` when the `main()` function returns. In turn, the `exit()` function will end up calling a thin-wrapper function named `_exit()` which (starting from `libc` v2.3) will finally invoke the  [exit_group](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/exit_group.2.html) system call and end up your process and also terminate all its threads.

This last system call is the one responsible for the behavior you noticed.

We can see this subtle note in the `_exit()` manual [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/exit.2.html):

```
C library/kernel differences
       In glibc up to version 2.3, the _exit() wrapper function invoked
       the kernel system call of the same name.  Since glibc 2.3, the
       wrapper function invokes exit_group(2), in order to terminate all
       of the threads in a process.
```

If your intention is to avoid this behavior, the only option is to call `pthread_exit` which will end your main thread and prevent you from returning to the `libc`'s `__libc_start_main()` function.

Answer (score -1):

As an aside on the same subject, I'd like to point out what seems to me an inaccuracy in the 3rd edition of APUE (Stevens & Rago). In section 7.3 it says "Normal termination occurs in five ways" and, among them it puts "Calling pthread_exit (Section 11.5) from the last thread". It seems to me that this is not true, because either main is still running (and pthread_exit doesn't terminate the program since main will do that) or main has already returned, so terminating the program, as this article correctly states.