# PThread Create doesn't create a thread

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, posix, semaphore

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "pthread.h"
#include "semaphore.h"

FILE * f;
sem_t * s1;
sem_t * s2;
int check;
int  v1;
int  v2;
int i;

static void * client (void *arg){


    sem_getvalue(s1, &v1); printf("Client pre wait(S1) in S1 => S1 = %d\n",v1);
    sem_wait(s1);
    printf("client works...\n");
    check = sem_getvalue(s1, &v1); printf("Client.wait(S1) in S1 => S1 = %d\n",v1);
    if(check != 0) printf("sem_getvalue error");


     return 0;
    }


int main(void){

    pthread_t tidc;
    pthread_t tids;
    int rc;
    int rs;

    //Semaforo 1
    s1 = (sem_t *) malloc(sizeof(sem_t));
    check = sem_init (s1, 0, 2);
    if (check != 0) perror("s1_init failed");




    sem_getvalue(s1, &v1);

    printf("Create the semaphores: S1 = %i\n",v1 );

    sem_wait(s1);
    printf("main waits\n");
    sem_getvalue(s1, &v1); printf("Main.wait(S1) in S1 => S1 = %d\n",v1);

    rc = pthread_create (&tidc, NULL, client, 0);
    printf(" thread created ==> rc= %i\n",rc);


    return 0;

   }
```

It returns this output:

```
Create the semaphores: S1 = 2
main waits
Main.wait(S1) in S1 => S1 = 1
 thread created ==> rc= 0
```

And sometimes this:

```
 Create the semaphores: S1 = 2
main waits
Main.wait(S1) in S1 => S1 = 1
 thread created ==> rc= 0
Client pre wait(S1) in S1 => S1 = 1
Client pre wait(S1) in S1 => S1 = 1
client works...
Client.wait(S1) in S1 => S1 = Client.wait(S1) in S1 => S1 = 0
```

Seems like sometimes creates two threads and sometimes no one. I compile with `gcc prog.c -lpthred` and even with `gcc -pthread prog.c`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [main thread exit, does other exit too?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875956/main-thread-exit-does-other-exit-too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a multithreaded program doesn't do the same thing from one execution to another, it could be because of uninitialized variables (like in non-threaded programs), but also can be because of a [*race condition*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510/what-is-a-race-condition).

In that case, the race condition is between thread execution and program exit.

Since you're exiting your main immediately after creating your threads, threads are terminated ([main thread exit, does other exit too?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875956/main-thread-exit-does-other-exit-too)). Sometimes, the thread has the time to do something, depending on the OS state & load.

If you add some actual processing, a long delay or a call to `pthread_join(tdic,NULL);` to wait for thread termination in your main program, you'll have deterministic behaviour.