# How to concurrently send data to multiple servers using C++ socket programming?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads

I deployed one program onto several servers (suppose the server IPs and the ports providing the service are `192.168.1.101:10001`, `192.168.1.102:10001`, `192.168.1.103:10001`, `192.168.1.104:10001`). They are all listening requests using the Linux `socket` apis and can finish the task independently.

Now, I want to concurrently send data to all four servers, so that they can concurrently executing the tasks.

I am sending the data using one Windows 10 PC, using C++ Socket. The basic procedure of `send_data` is as follows:

```
void send_data(string& server_ip, string& server_port, vector<char>& buf) {
    struct addrinfo ...;           // set the server information
    SOCKET socket = socket(...);   // create the socket object
    connect(socket, ...);          // connect the server
    send(socket, buf, ...);        // send the buf data
}
```

This is OK when sending sequentially data into the four servers, e.g.,

```
vector<char> bufdata(...);
char* server_ips = {"192.168.1.101", "192.168.1.102", "192.168.1.103", "192.168.1.104"};
char* port = "10001";
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    send_data(server_ips[i], port, bufdata);
}
```

What I expect is the host client can concurrently send the data. I have tried the following method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    std::thread t(send_data, server_ips[i], port, bufdata); 
}
```

But the program will exit with no luck.

Could you please help give some advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure this is the only problem, but given what you shared, the main thread is not waiting for the worker threads to finish their tasks.

Per this answer: [When the main thread exits, do other threads also exit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11875956/5755321), the process will be terminated when the main thread returns from `main()`.

Proposed fix:

```cpp
int main() {
    // .. your logic here
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        std::thread t(send_data, server_ips[i], port, bufdata); 
        threads.push_back(std::move(t));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        if (threads[i].joinable())
            threads[i].join(); // wait for threads[i] to finish
    }

    // .. clean up
}
```

Comment: `std::thread t(send_data, server_ips[i], port, bufdata); threads.push_back(std::move(t));` can be simplified to `threads.emplace_back(send_data, server_ips[i], port, bufdata);` Also, you don't need to check `joinable()`  before calling `join()` in this use case

Answer (score 1):

You aren't [joining](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/join/) or [detaching](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/detach/) the threads causing the program to exit with errors. Store the threads in an array so you can join them or call detach in your loop.

Comment: Yeah, it worked! Thank you!

Comment: Don't detach the threads in this case. You'll still run into a problem where the program exits while the threads are still running. You need to join the threads before exiting